# how to set multiple overlay modal for sencha component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button in my application when clicked a panel appears and overlay window created, on the newly created panel i have another button when clicked opens another window with overlay.

ideally upper panel should block the access to underneath panel but still let user access the underneath panel.

panel 1

```
app.views.EventForm = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'eventFormPanel',
    layout: 'hbox',
    floating: true,
    modal: true,
})
```

panel 2

```
app.views.RecurringOptions= new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'RecurringOptions',
    layout: 'hbox',
    floating: true,
    modal: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

set the hideOnMaskTap property as true which means when user clicks outside the second overlay it disappears and the first overlay is shown...

Hope it helps